# Casting Parameter Variables from int to char and vice-versa

Tags: java, parameters, casting, char, int

If I pass a char as a parameter when calling stuff, will it compile? Will passing an int instead of a char work too? I know you can cast from int to char but shouldn't it be explicit?

I have a class Test with one static method of return type String with char a and int x as parameters.

```
public class Test {
    public static String stuff(char a, int x)
    {
        char b = (char)x; String s = "";
        while (a<b)
        s+=a+b--;
        return s;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         System.out.println(stuff('a','d'));
    }
}
```

Comment: char can take upto 255

Comment: and yes it will compile.

Comment: Why can you pass a char as an int? Passing 'd' instead of an int.

Comment: because char can support upto 255, above that value it will not support and compiler will complain loss of precision

Comment: Why didn't it require you to explicitly cast it

Comment: If you go above the given range you have to cast it explicitly.

Comment: char has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Comment: Does this apply to any other casting? ex. int to byte, float to int

Comment: If memory serves casting to a larger value is usually implicit, but you'll need an explicit cast to go to a variable with less precision

Comment: java implicitly treat every data type as a int. See [this](http://www.studytonight.com/java/type-casting-in-java.php)

Comment: Thanks Mr.Pandey make that into an answer

Comment: @inventorbc:I have posted an answer, hope that shed some light on you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up-casting(implicit)-

> byte –> short –> int –> long –> float –> double

Down-casting(Explicit)-

> double –> float –> long –> int–> short–> byte

int takes 4 bytes of memory and char takes 2 bytes of memory, so requires explicit casting. int can take negative values and char takes only positive values.

```
      public class Test {
      public static void main(String args[]) { 
      int i = 78;     // 4 bytes 
      // char ch = i;   // error, 4 bytes to 2 bytes
      char ch = (char) i; // int is type converted to char
      System.out.println(ch); // prints N (78 ASCII value for N)

      System.out.println("Max int:"+Integer.SIZE+"bit");
      System.out.println("Max char:"+Character.SIZE+"bit");

       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes passing a char is legal,but not good practice.